# How to inherit stan's S4 class

Tags: stan, rstan

I develop some package using `rstan::stan()`. I make a function whose return value is an S4 class object generated by `rstan::stan()`.  To access estimates comfortablely or to add an information for data, I want to make a new S4 class object which inherits S4 class of `rstan::stan()`so that there is new slots.

Furthermore, the new S4class object also can be available for any functions in `rstan` such as `rstan::traceplot()`.

---

```
fit  <-  rstan::stan( model_name=scr, data=data) # This is a fictitious code.
```

Suppose we get S4 (stanfit) object named `fit` .

Define an extended class of stanfit

```
InheritedClass  <- setClass("InheritedClass",

             # New slots
               representation(slotA="character",
                              slotB="character",
                              slotC="numeric"),


               contains = "stanfit"
)
```

To create an S4 object of the inherited class  ***using an existing S4 class object*** ,i.e., `fit`, 
 so what I need is only  to input  values for added new slots, i.e., slotA, slotB, slotC.

Using the following code, we can convert the S4 object for old class to inherited class:

```
fit2 <- as(fit,"InheritedClass")
```

Using this we can edit slot like following:

```
   fit2@slotA <- "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `help(setClass)`. I believe it would be something like

```
setClass("classname", slots = c(foo = "numeric", bar = "character"),
         contains = "stanfit")
```

And I'm sure you would have to include **rstan** in the `Imports:` line of the DESCRIPTION file in your package in order for it to find the S4 class definition for `stanfit`.